# WordPress Widget Text - how to display it anywhere manually?

Tags: wordpress, widget, wordpress-4.3

How can I get the WP widget text manually?

I try with this code being displayed:

```
<?php the_widget( 'WP_Widget_Text' ); ?>
```

But I have nothing being displayed.

Anything specific I need to pass in this function? I created the widget text and called it 'Follow Me':

[image]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a sidebar and put the text widget inside that sidebar.

Suppose ID of your created sidebar id "sidebar-2"

If you only want to display the Text Widget then don't add other widget in sidebar-2 , that is create a separate sidebar for Text Widget, because all the widgets included in sidebar is called by below function.

You can paste this function where you want your text widget to be displayed.

```
if ( is_active_sidebar( 'sidebar-2' ) ) : ?>
    <div id="tertiary" class="sidebar-container" role="complementary">
        <div class="sidebar-inner">
            <div class="widget-area">
                <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'sidebar-2' ); ?>
            </div><!-- .widget-area -->
        </div><!-- .sidebar-inner -->
    </div><!-- #tertiary -->
<?php endif; ?>
```

Create new siebar for Text Widget Only :

```
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'theme_slug_widgets_init' );
function theme_slug_widgets_init() {
    register_sidebar( array(
        'name' => __( 'Main Sidebar', 'theme-slug' ),
        'id' => 'sidebar-2',
        'description' => __( 'Widgets in this area will be shown on all posts and pages.', 'theme-slug' ),
        'before_widget' => '<li id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
    'after_widget'  => '</li>',
    'before_title'  => '<h2 class="widgettitle">',
    'after_title'   => '</h2>',
    ) );
}
```

> ID of the sidebar is used to call the sidebar at required place in our case "sidebar-2"
>
> ID of the sidebar should be in lower case and can contain "-".

Answer (score 1):

If you want to call widget use this function

```
<?php the_widget( 'your-widget-title' ); ?>
```

for your widget

```
<?php the_widget( 'Follow Me' ); ?>
```

Comment: once check only some "hello" text instead of this linkedin and twitter link

Comment: sorry i dont understand

Comment: i think there may be some problem in your widget content part so try normal text because i have try this and its work for me.